# SQLite C# Error: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error unrecognized token: "'Income""'

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Currently, I have a piece of code which displays the Table in DataGridView

```
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(DBC.connectionstring))
{
    con.Open();
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Income", con);
    DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Info");
    IncomeData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];                           
}
```

However, because I am going to have to reuse the code multiple time. I decided to create a new class allowing me to do so. As shown below:

```
public void DBLoad(string tableName, DataGridView DGVname)
    {
        DBC = new DatabaseConnection();
        DBC.getConnection() // connects to .db file

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(DBC.connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM '" + tableName + '"', con);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds, "Info");
            DGVname.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

But the problem I am having is that the `tableName` is going to be in the SQL query and I keep running into the problem of needing to remove the quotation marks.

If I do this:

```
className.DBLoad("Income", IncomeData);
```

Then the following error occurs:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error unrecognized token: "'Income""'

I tried doing:

```
tableName = tableName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

But I still get the same error. So now I don't know what do to.

Comment: Your first snippet doesnt use a tick, so why does the second, particularly in light of the message complaining about `'Income'`?  This is generally a bad idea anyway

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain what do you mean by a tick?

Comment: Why do you put single quotes around the variable _tablename_ in your generic query? A tablename should not be treated as a string. By the way, be sure that your users cannot type the value for that variable or bad things could happen

Comment: change to `$"SELECT * FROM {tableName}"`

Comment: @Matt.G This works. Thank You.

Comment: @SonnyP. mind checking the answer and upvote and select as answer if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know you don't need ticks near the table name .

> The tick is : '

i also recommend you use the `String.Format` method as follows to replace the table name inside the query :

```
String.Format("Select * FROM {0}",tableName);
```

so this line of code :

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM '" + tableName + '"', con);
```

should be like this :

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(String.Format("Select * FROM {0}",tableName), con);
```

**References :**

[SQLite SELECT - Querying data from a single table](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select/)

[String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2)